# What should we do when encountering a useless, but time-consuming, answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, contribution

I don't want to give the link because you may vote down if you see the answer. The answer is totally useless and not related to my question. However, I can confirm that the author spent a lot of time on his answer. What should I do to recognize this (useless) contribution?

I have thought of four choices:

1. Do nothing.
2. Vote the answer up to thank him for spending his time.
3. Vote the answer down, because useless it's useless.
4. Leave a comment to thank him for spending the time, but tell him that his answer is totally useless.

I think 4th option is good, but it's too rude!

Comment: Without further details it's hard to judge into what category that answer falls.

Comment: Links, or it didn't happen =)  If it's an incorrect answer it will get downvoted anyway (and should!)

Comment: I think I would better understand your question if I could read his question. I promise I won't -1 it :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, fixed. To Bobby and jadarnel: I'm asking a solution to a algorithm, and he just gave me a long explanation with, most of them, are out of topic.

Comment: I can give example: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39343/is-lag-compensation-affecting-my-performance - the "answer" explaining very well what lag compensation is, but **completely** ignoring specific question I've asked. I chose option 4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect I know the answer you mean; assuming so, I would suggest a comment explaining how a: it has misunderstood the question, and b: the result of their answer doesn't match the stated requirements from the question.

As it happens, I *have* also downvoted it, because it so much *doesn't* address the question that it is noise and therefore subtracts value (in particular, the time of people reading it, and the resultant head-scratching).

So I vote 4 **and** 3. It isn't rude to point out what is obviously a misunderstanding.

NOT **2**. Anything but 2.

---

Update: and now I believe the user has deleted their answer, removing the "noise"; yet because of the comment they could see what the downvote was about, and how they had misinterpreted the question. Ends well, IMO.

Comment: LOL, you're genius. He was -1 by someone, so I +1 him, and now that answer gone. Maybe he realise that his answer content was mostly off-topic.

Comment: @W.N.: Do not pity-upvote stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I would leave a comment explaining why you can't give his well-thought question a good answer. And I wouldn't upvote or downvote, since you said that he put some effort into the question.

Comment: While it may be true that they put effort into it, please look at what the caption on the downvote *is*; it is "This answer is not useful". Seems like it describes this example...

Comment: Even so, I only down vote bad questions. If the asker put a lot of effort into a question, but its still a useless question and they do not understand why, I would not down vote. Depends on the question, which in this situation I cannot read the question so I am unsure of how I would vote.

Comment: (we're talking answers, not questions, no?)

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh my god... I read the question wrong.. Either way, I would respond to it the same, in fact if it was a useless answer that had a lot of effort put in it, I wouldn't downvote ^_^

Comment: @Gabe -- I would (and do) absolutely downvote a useless answer. The point of upvoting and downvoting is not to give or remove rep or to make people feel good.  The point is to make sure that the useful answers are easy to find.  Downvoting non-useful answers is part of how we do that.